# If two apps use the same partition name in chrome, can one steal the cookie of the other?

Tags: security, cookies, google-chrome-app

You can embed any pages in a chrome app like so:

```
   <webview id="secure" src="https://www.site-with-secure-login.com" 
     partition="persist:alphaNum123" style="width:640px; height:480px">
   </webview>

   <webview id="malware" src="https://www.something-secret-malicious.com" 
     partition="persist:alphaNum123" style="width:0px; height:0px">
   </webview>
```

If two apps used the same partition value, would they have access to each others' cookies?

Answer (score 0):

If two different *Chrome apps* used the same partition name, nothing would happen. Chrome does not expect developers to come up with unique names.

If the above code was inside *one* Chrome app, then cookies would be shared, that's the point of partitions.

However, standard web security applies; `https://www.something-secret-malicious.com` still can't normally access cookies for another domain `https://www.site-with-secure-login.com`. It would be like 2 tabs open in the same browser. If you then navigated to the *same* site, cookies will apply.

Comment: Perhaps relatedly, is it possible to sync these app partitions across device  (as far as I know, cookies are accessible through extensions).

Comment: Although not addressing partitions, this is a good resource: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15259/worst-case-scenario-what-can-a-chrome-extension-do-with-your-data-on-all-websi

Comment: Michael, this has _nothing_ to do with Chrome App webview partitions.

Comment: Nevertheless it's a good resource, and it is related enough that anyone interested in partition vulnerabilities would be interested in general cookie access by extensions.